# How to deploy an x86 package to a Windows Phone device?

Tags: windows-phone-8

When I have tried to run an x86 on my device, the following error happened:

> Unable to deploy an x86 package to a Windows Phone device. Change the build configuration to ARM or Neutral or change the Debug Target to an emulator.

Is there a way to run the app on the device without changing the build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer, **no**.

It is not possible to run a x86 package on an ARM device (which is the case).
You will need to change the target to ARM or Neutral just as the error suggests.

Comment: Meneses is correct - it's simply not possible to execute an x86 package on an ARM processor, at least without a virtual runtime environment, and Windows Phone doesn't have one of those.

Comment: but what type of xap i need to upload on store to make it work on all devices, x86/x64/ARM ? Note that I am using SQLite in my project so I cant select AnyCPU

Comment: @TaLhaKhan you can add one of each if you'd like.

Comment: @Meneses windows phone doesnot allow to upload more than 1 package.

Comment: @TaLhaKhan Yes it does. I just tested it. When you upload a package, you have "Replace", "Delete" and below that row corresponding your package you have "Add new"

Comment: @Meneses Yes it has Add new button, but when I added a new package and error occured, only 1 package is allowed.........anyways, i got the answer. only ARM packages need to be uploaded on store.